# why does taskset have no effect on fedora?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, parallel-processing, cpu-cores

I am trying to run a highly multi-threaded application and want to measure its performance with different cores ( 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 ... 12). I saw taskset when googled,

```
taskset 0x00000003 ./my_app
```

but when I see system monitor of the fedora, It only shows one core doing 100% and others only 12%, 0%,...etc.
Is there any way to tell the process to run on certain core. I also heard of an option like -t #no of cores . like

```
./my_app -t2
```

for 0 and 1 core .. but this also have no effect 
what am I doing wrong can any one please lead me to right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`taskset 0x00000003 ./my_app` sets the affinity of the my_app process to cores 1 and 2. If your application is multithreaded, the threads inherit the affinity, but their distribution between core 1 and 2 is not set.

To set the affinity of each thread within your process, you can either use taskset after the process is running (i.e. run myapp, examine the thread ids and call `taskset -pc <core> <tid>` for each) or set the affinity at thread creation with `sched_setaffinity`, `pthread_setaffinity_np` if you are using pthreads etc).

Whatever `./myapp -t2` does is specific to you application.

Comment: thank you @jmetcalfe .. are using -t2 and taskset similar.. when I try to run after running the program like taskset -pc 2 29537 , still there is no effect that I can see on the system monitor(runs with one core only)

Comment: the effect of that command is to move process 29537 to core 2. If you want to force two particular threads onto 2 cores, you need two taskset commands, one for each thread

Comment: how about taskset -pc 0-1 5984 . (5984 is process id of my_app). would this divide the process into 0 and 1 core ?? assuming that the process have many pthreads running in back ground of the process .. And also do you know any other way to force the program to run in particular thread, what I have learned so far is It can be done but the program I am running also have to support it

Comment: It will mean the process can operate on those 2 cores. How it actually utilises that ability depends on the thread structure of the application, scheduling set up etc. Under default scheduling, if, for example, the application contains two threads both spinning, you would expect the OS to allocate the two threads to different cores eventually. I'm not sure what you mean by forcing the program to run in a particular thread. What are your threads doing?

Comment: sorry I meant particular core .. my_app creates many thread and those individual thread calculate certain value and latter I collect those value .. so doing taskset -pc 1 5984 should run my_app in core 1. But instead the system monitor shows 100% use in core 0 and 13% use in core 1. When i said 1 in (taskset -pc 1 5984) why still the program run in core 0 ? ... (sorry for bad enlgish )

Comment: -t command was told by friend .. do you know where I can find documentation for this command .. I tried googling but could not find any

Comment: If you run taskset -pc 1 ./myapp rather than applying it to the pid afterwards, do you see the expected behaviour? The ./myapp -t2 thing is not something anyone can help you with as it is specific to your application. If it is supported you will find some code in your applicaion that deals with it.

Comment: I tried using ./myapp -t2 and ./myapp -t1 .. I can see the time difference . It take 3.43sec with t2 and 1.88 sec with t1 (machine has only two core). What amazes me is when I try wiht -t4 ( machine has only two core) It just takes longer time. How could It even work taking longer time if I have only two core? Isnt the argument after t number of core?

Comment: Noone can tell you without seeing all your code. The -t is not some generic argument you can pass in to any program - it is something in your code. However, assuming that it controls the number of worker threads or similar, it is perfectly reasonable that you see performance degradation when increasing it beyond the number of cores. This is essentially because you now have 2 threads competing for each core - they are not able to do any more work before, but they still incur the extra cost of synchronisation and swapping between threads.